# Getting the last executed command on a screen

Tags: gnu-screen

I have a command that is fetching some information from the internet and entering it into a database. To ensure it keeps running, I am running the task on an `AWS` instance with a `screen` command.

I need to see the various parameters that that command was executed with? How can I see the currently running/last executed command on another `screen`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options with job control:

1. you ran the command as `screen mycommand -abc -other -args`. In this case, use <kbd>Ctrl a</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> to detach. Then cursor up or type `history | tail`. Use `screen -r` to reattach.
2. you started `screen` and ran your command in the new session. In this scenario you can (probably) <kbd>Ctrl z</kbd> to suspend the process. Then cursor up or type `history | tail`. Use `fg` to continue the process as before.

Comment: Thanks. Point 2 is what I ended up doing. I was fearful that the process might be lost, even with `fg`, but that was not the case. Thanks much!

Comment: You can use `echo "!!"` too. Prints the last command

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:
1. Use "screen -x " command to attach to the existing screen session
2. Do "C-a Escape" to Enter scrollback/copy mode.

Once in scrollback mode, you can use the regular movement keys (Search for "Movement keys" in the "man screen" page to find different movement options) to scroll back up to the point where the command is executed which should show the parameters.

If the scrollback bufffer is too small or the command spews too many lines of output, refer to screen man page or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760346/how-do-i-increase-the-scrollback-buffer-in-a-running-screen-session and set scrollback buffer size to a big enough number.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The command is still executing and outputs a lot of debugging messages. I don't think scrolling might help.

Comment: If the command execution lines are still available in the scrollback buffer, you could just type "g" to jump to the beginning of the scrollback buffer which should show what you need (Search for "Movement keys" in the "man screen" page to find other movement options).

If your scrollback bufffer is too small or your command spews too many lines of output, refer to man page or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760346/how-do-i-increase-the-scrollback-buffer-in-a-running-screen-session and set scrollback buffer size to a higher number.